# Transferring Master to Master, different country/ LOR issue

Tags: masters, recommendation-letter, transfer-student

I'm currently undertaking second semester in MA program. 
As an international student, I am unhappy with living here in this country, so I'm considering to transfer to another university in the US but a similar MA program.

In this case I need to take GRE which wasn't required in order to get in the current university, and hopefully meet the minimum requirements. 
In this case can I make an excuse about unhappiness when asking for a letter of recommendation (LOR) from my supervisor?

Well then I need at least three LORs, but I have no idea where to ask for. I do have been volunteering at an organization for almost over 100 hours now, but is unpaid work okay to be considered as a strong LOR?

Comment: I don't think you can transfer your masters study from one university in one country to another university in another country. You will need to re-apply. About the LoR, how did you get in your current masters program? Did they need LoRs? When you come back, please delete the last gibberish paragraph.

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment. And you're right the current one didnt require LORs. Here was quite an easy move for me at that time.

Comment: Plus I already contacted to the one that Im willing to transfer to. They said they can take up to 6 credits from my current univ.

Comment: Is the organisation you are volunteering at related to your studies?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine for a moment that you are a trailing spouse.  You have fallen in love with someone with a job in City X, and s/he is not in a position to relocate.  Transfers in this case happen all the time, and there would be very little difficulty in asking for a letter of recommendation (LOR).

I suggest you say to your supervisor, "I love the coursework here and I love working with you, but it's become necessary for me to transfer to City X for personal reasons.  Would you be comfortable writing me a letter of recommendation for University X?"

If you have a close relationship with your supervisor, and s/he asks you what the personal reasons are, AND IF YOU **WANT TO** REVEAL MORE INFORMATION, then you can add, "the culture and surroundings here are just torturing me."  But probably it would be best to leave this out, especially if you are not 100% certain your supervisor will not spread your comments around.

Bravo to you for taking care of yourself.